# Disambiguating 繰り返して: て form vs standalone word

Tags: grammar, て-form

In the dictionary, 繰り返して is shown to have a special meaning "repeatedly". Of course, the regular て form is the same. Which of the two is meant in constructs such as

> われわれは数知れない失敗を繰り返してきた

> これを繰り返していけば…

For reference, here's how the 研究社 5th edition lists this word:

```
くりかえす【繰り返す】 (kurikaesu)
repeat; do over again; duplicate; 《文》 reiterate.
おうむ返しに繰り返す　repeat 《sb's words》 like a parrot; echo [parrot] 《sb's words》
・繰り返して　repeatedly; over and over (again); again and again; time and (time) again
・繰り返して言う　say over (and over) again; repeat; 《文》 reiterate
```

Comment: Is 繰り返して listed separately from 繰り返す in your dictionary? It is nothing but the て-form of 繰り返す.

Comment: Yes, updated the question. If it's just a て form, how is the meaning created with いけば in my example sentence?

Comment: What you are asking seems to be how to tell whether verbs like いく and くる are used as subsidiary verbs or main verbs in general. It doesn’t seem to be limited to when they are used after 繰り返して.

Comment: Perhaps, but I haven't encountered such ambiguities with other verbs. If you happen to see any posts here or elsewhere on this topic, could you please share?

Comment: For example, 歩いていく can mean either walking to some place or going on walking (into the future). In the first interpretation, 歩いて could be seen as an adverb modifying the verb 行く, while in the second, 歩いて and いく cannot be separated. Your sentences are much less ambiguous. Actually, they are not ambiguous at all. For 繰り返して to be an independent adverb, 失敗をきた and これをいけば have to make sense. While there may be some possibility with the latter, the former makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

繰り返して is nothing but the て-form of 繰り返す. I find it a bit odd that it is listed as if it is a standalone adverb in your dictionary. 繰り返し, with a ます-stem ending, seems more qualified as one. In comparison, 繰り返して is clearly a verb and, being transitive, sounds much more natural when it is used with a direct object than otherwise.

Both your examples do have a direct object, as indicated with brackets below.

> われわれは［数知れない失敗を］繰り返してきた

> ［これを］繰り返していけば…

If 繰り返して were an adverb, the sentences would be grammatical without it, but that doesn’t seem to be the case.

> x われわれは数知れない失敗をきた

> ? これをいけば…

Comment: I assume you used the ?  instead of x with いけば because it could be grammatical if これ referred to a road, etc? E.g., "If you could repeatedly take this path" -- a somewhat weird but possible meaning?

Comment: @max - Yes, weird but possible. In fact, it would be the only possible interpretation if 繰り返し was used instead of 繰り返し**て**. With て, it's very hard to read it that way.

Answer (score 2):

繰り返して comes from 繰り返す. It is being used a lot in Japanese as you use the word 'repeat' a lot in English.

'~~~繰り返してきた' can be interpreted as "We have been repeatedly gone through ~~~."

<verb+て> words can never be put in dictionaries by itself.
I've just searched for some related Japanese texts in Google whether there are some exceptions, but I couldn't find one. (Comments are welcomed if there are any exception for them).

However, some phrases like ＜～て＋いく＞、＜～て＋くる＞ can be introduced as independent expressions or idioms in Japanese.

Explaining the usage of '~てform' (て形 in Japanese) would need a small book to cover all of them. (Imagine you are explaining someone the usage of 'which', 'that', 'who', 'where' in English)

So I recommend you to be just be familiar with the language itself first, then study deeper more about the theoretical things.

However, you will be surprised someday that even Japanese don't know much about the theories of Japanese by themselves. So please just to be familiar with the language itself. Good luck!